# What does nested function mean in C?

Tags: c, syntax

```
void t(){
    printf("hello\n");
    void s(){
        printf("2\n");
    }   
}
int main(){
    t();
    return 0;                                                                                                                                 
}
```

After I call `t()`, `s` should be defined, but seems it's not the case.

Is it just ignored ?

Comment: Are you using GCC with the [nested functions extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) enabled? Note that standard C does not support nested functions, so this will very likely not compile on other C compilers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well known languages supporting [lexically nested functions include](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_function):

- ALGOL-based languages such as ALGOL 68, Simula, Pascal, Modula-2, Modula-3, Oberon and Ada.
- Modern versions of Lisp (with lexical scope) such as Scheme, and Common Lisp.
- ECMA Script (JavaScript, and ActionScript).
- Full support in Scala
- Various degrees of support in scripting languages such as Ruby, Python, and Perl (starting with version 6).
- There is also a C-related language with nested functions, the D language.
- GCC also supports nested functions in C, as a language extension.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_function)
- Fortran, starting with Fortran-90, supports one level of nested (CONTAINed) subroutines and functions.

In your case, function `s` will only be available within `t`.

A nested function is a function defined inside another function. (Nested functions are not supported for GNU C++.) The nested function's name is local to the block where it is defined. For example, here we define a nested function named square, and call it twice:

```
 foo (double a, double b)
 {
   double square (double z) { return z * z; }

   return square (a) + square (b);
 }
```

The nested function can access all the variables of the containing function that are visible at the point of its definition. This is called lexical scoping. For example, here we show a nested function which uses an inherited variable named offset:

```
 bar (int *array, int offset, int size)
 {
   int access (int *array, int index)
     { return array[index + offset]; }
   int i;
   /* ... */
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
     /* ... */ access (array, i) /* ... */
 }
```

Nested function definitions are permitted within functions in the places where variable definitions are allowed; that is, in any block, mixed with the other declarations and statements in the block.

See ["Nested Functions - Using the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC)"](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html)

Comment: @cnicutar: I am referencing the links provided :)

Comment: Let me emphasize that nested functions are a gcc-specific extension; they're not permitted by the standard C language.  If you want your code to be portable to compilers other than gcc, avoid them.

Answer (score 2):

Actually `s` will only be available within `t`. Quoting the link posted by In silico:

> The nested function's name is **local to the block** where it is defined.

Comment: Is this defined in standard c syntax or gcc only?

Comment: @R__ It's a non-standard extension supported by a few compilers.

Answer (score -1):

In C, functions and their scope (where their name can be used) are defined and fixed at compile time.  If you want to change what a function name does during runtime, you need to use function pointers.